# Apply filters on HBase Column Family

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a table in HBase which contains data as per below:

EmployeeDetails:

```
 997942                                column=Employee_details:Qualifications, timestamp=1520592579241, value=$ EmployeeCode:02404#EmployeeName:ABC
                                       #EducationLevel:#Course:#SubjectOfSpecialization:#InstituteName:#UniversityName:#CourseType:#ScoreType:#Sc
                                       ore:#StartYear:#EndYear:#EduHistoryID:#EmploymentStatus:Exited#ModifiedDate:#MinorSpecialization:General#IsTra
                                       ck:Yes#OrganizationID:19
 997942                                column=Employee_details:RefferelDetails, timestamp=1520592579241, value=$ EmployeeCode:02404#EmployeeName:ABC
                                       #Name:#ContactNumber:#Email:#Designation:#OrganizationName:#OrganizationAddress:#ReferenceRelationshipTyp
                                       e:#IsInternalReference:No#EmployeeCodeRef:#EmploymentStatus:Exited#EmployeeReferenceDetailID:#ModifiedDate:Nov
                                        16 2015  5:52PM#OrganizationID:19
 997942                                column=Employee_details:Skills, timestamp=1520592579241, value=$ EmployeeCode:02404#EmployeeName:ABC#Cer
                                       tificateLevel:#IsCompleted:#CompletionDate:#EmploymentStatus:Exited#ModifiedDate:#OrganizationID:19
 997942                                column=Employee_details:organizationid, timestamp=1520592579241, value=19
```

997942 is the key of this table. I want to pull the records only for OrganizationID = 19 using Java and for doing this, I have written the below code:

```
HTable table = new HTable(config, "EmployeeDetails");
FilterList list = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Employee_details"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("organizationid"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf("19"))));
list.addFilter(filter);
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(list);
scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Data for all the Organizations is getting pulled. Filter is not working correctly. Do we have any alternative for this?

Comment: As an aside, your column names are very long, which results in more data being moved + stored every time you do an operation.

Comment: Do you really mean `HTable table = new HTable(config, "TableName");`? Replace `"TableName"` with `"EmployeeDetails"`. And consider starting smaller - can you do a scan that retrieves all rows of that table? Then add a simpler Filter? Then build it up to your desired functionality.

Comment: I wrote "TableName" because it is filled dynamically. e.g. EmployeeDetails will be passed in case I am fetching EmployeeDetails data.

Comment: If I run the scan on Hbase shell and then add filters one by one, code is working perfectly fine but Java api is not working

Comment: What if you just do the scan without filters in Java?

Comment: It returns the complete data contained in that table

Comment: @whywake can you please add another dataset, which should not be included in the scan? i.e. a negative dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with

```
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(TableName),
    Bytes.toBytes("organizationid"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(organizationId))));
```

`SingleColumnValueFilter`'s constructor has the signature

```
SingleColumnValueFilter(final byte [] family, final byte [] qualifier,
   final CompareOp compareOp, final byte[] value)
```

You're giving the first argument as TableName, when it should be column family.

Instead use:

```
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Employee_details"),
    Bytes.toBytes("organizationid"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    Bytes.toBytes(organizationId));
```

Also you don't need a `FilterList`, as you're only using one Filter.

Comment: Apologies for my previous code, I am using ColumnFamily only. Edited the above code.

Comment: Please can you clean up your question so that it shows exactly what you're actually running as a minimum example for recreating this error? So no undefined variables, no generic strings etc. It'll help me a lot. As it stands, it's still incorrect (`new HTable(config, "ColumnFamilyName");` should be the table name), and I think the entire `BandDetails` is unnecessary as it's not involved anywhere.

Comment: TableName & ColumnFamily were being populated dynamically and I swapped both the values by mistake. Fixed both of them now. Band table is added for reference to depict that this code is working fine in one case and not in other.

Comment: It still says `new HTable(config, "TableName");`, and `ColumnFamilyName` and `organizationId` are undefined. It's impossible to properly debug this without knowing exactly what you run to get this error.

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: Thanks for doing that. It looks OK to me, especially strange given it works on the other table and through the shell... No chance it's a data issue?

Comment: Does not seems to me. Below script on Hbase shell is giving correct results.

scan 'EmployeeDetails' ,{ FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('Employee_details','organizationid',=, 'binary:19')" }

Comment: Have you tried setting the last argument to `    Bytes.toBytes(organizationId));`?

Comment: This is what you mean to say?

SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Employee_details"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("organizationid"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(organizationid)));

Comment: Sure, but you can ditch the `new BinaryComparator()` wrapper, as the HBase code automatically adds it for you.

Comment: Can't do that as 19 is the dynamic value set for organizationid parameter.